# how to make a cronjob run, when user needs to be logged in

Tags: multisite, login, cron

My multisite wordpress site works the way, that if someone is not logged in, they will be redirected to wp-login.php.
Unfortunately i have a cronjob, that can not run, because it is also redirected, since its not a logged in user, who runs it.
How can i get this to work ? Im posting my script below. It seems like, after wp-load.php is run, i can not get anything to work.

```
// Include WordPress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('/var/www/intranet.fo/public_html/wp-load.php');

// wp_set_auth_cookie(9);

// $creds = array();
// $creds['user_login'] = 'my_username';
// $creds['user_password'] = 'my_pw';
// $creds['remember'] = true;
// $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

Comment: you can load wp-cron.php directly via a proper cron job, this is actually recommended by wordpress, see this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/253331/76440

Comment: are you saying that i will get rid of the not logged in redirection, by doing it this way ?

Comment: it should bypass the user redirection because there is no user session as such to process, the WP Cron tasks are called directly instead, by calling wp-cron.php instead of wp-load.php

Comment: that sounds great, i will try it later today