# WordPress Multisite cron jobs using cron tab

Tags: wp-cron

U have a WordPress multisite install with subfolders. U'm trying to set up cron jobs. I know I can setup for each site with,

```
HTTP_HOST=sub.example.com php wp-cron.php > /dev/null
```

But this doesn't work for subfolders. I also know I can use wget or curl. But is there a way for doing it with php?

**Edit:** Not a duplicate of suggested question because I clearly mentioned that I have a subfolder install. Answers to that question mostly include wp-cli and some scripts. I don't need that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running WP Cron on multisite the right way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167238/running-wp-cron-on-multisite-the-right-way)

Comment: I quote **I also know I can use wget or curl. But is there a way for doing it with php?**

Comment: The beste future safe way is to use WP CLI. The [second answer in the linked question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239257/108180) also includes a PHP only example

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but if you don't want to use WP-CLI and ONLY want to use crontab tasks, you would have to add new crontab job for each subsite, like:

```
curl -s https://example.com/[directory]/wp-cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Ref: https://vpsfix.com/7456/setup-proper-cron-jobs-wordpress-multisite-network/

You said your crons are not working for subfolders, but you don't provide any error messages or explain why it's not working... however, it should work, if you follow this.

I don't think you can avoid using wget/curl, unless you write a custom PHP script, you can see this for one example of that:

https://sabrinazeidan.com/fixing-WordPress-multisite-cron/