# When hooking wp-cron to system

Tags: multisite, wp-cron

When hooking wp-cron to system, for the multisite. Do i need to setup cron setup?

wget --delete-after http://YOUR_SITE_URL_1/wp-cron.php

wget --delete-after http://YOUR_SITE_URL_2/wp-cron.php

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "setup cron setup" ? Are you asking where to put those two lines, or do you mean do you need to do something other than those two lines (and the other config in the article you linked to), or something else?

Comment: I mean when hooking wp cron in to system what is recommended command to mutilate.

Comment: @rup are you know about how we can setup cron jobs trigger from the system other than default wp cron. And this is guide for it. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/ my question when come to mutisite. How these Linux command should need to be ? just a clarification I needed it should as above example or not ? if not what is command.

Comment: Oh, right, you meant "multisite" not "mutilate" - that makes more sense. Yes, I think you do need to call wp-cron.php on each site, and as far as I know what you've got there should work as system cron jobs, yes.

Comment: It you did want to use something else though then you can use wp-cli, and there's [an old question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167238/3276) about setting that up to automatically detect all of the multisites and run wp_cron jobs from a schedule. But if you only have a few sites that's probably more complicated than you need.

Comment: Great thanks any apologies my mistyping, I was bit hurry find answer for this questions